# Android chat app crashes due to java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My chat app crashes when I receive a message from another device. It was made with android studio and firebase. This is the exception I'm getting : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at

```
for (User user1 : nUsers) {
```

Present in the readChats():

```
 private void readChats() {
        nUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                nUsers.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for (String id : usersList){
                        if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                            if (nUsers.size() != 0) {
                                 for (User user1 : nUsers) {
                                    if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId()))
                                        nUsers.add(user);
                                }
                            } else {
                                nUsers.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The whole code:

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {
   
       private RecyclerView recyclerView;
       private userAdapter userAdapter;    private List<User> nUsers;
       FirebaseUser fuser;    DatabaseReference reference;
       private List<String> usersList;
       @Override    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
   
       recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.chat_list);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((getContext())));
   
       fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   
       usersList = new ArrayList<>();
   
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
       reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   
               usersList.clear();
               for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                   Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
   
                   assert chat != null;
                   if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                       usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                   }
                   if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                       usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                   }
               }
               readChats();
           }
   
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
   
           }
       });
       return view;    }
       private void readChats() {
       nUsers = new ArrayList<>();
   
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
   
       reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               nUsers.clear();
   
               for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                   User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
   
                   for (String id : usersList){
                       if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                           if (nUsers.size() != 0) {
                                for (User user1 : nUsers) {
                                   if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId()))
                                       nUsers.add(user);
                               }
                           } else {
                               nUsers.add(user);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
   
               userAdapter = new userAdapter(getContext(), nUsers);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
           }
   
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
   
           }
       });    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are adding item in the same list on which you are iterating with foreach loop e.g

```
for (User user1 : nUsers) {
               if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId()))
                    nUsers.add(user);
}
```

Java Collection classes are fail-fast which means that if the Collection will be changed while some thread is traversing over it using iterator, the iterator.next() will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

This situation can come in case of multithreaded as well as single threaded environment. - [www.javacodegeeks.com](http://www.javacodegeeks.com)

Calling .add() inside the for/each loop modifies the contents, and the Iterator that is used behind the scenes sees this and throws this exception

**Solutions**

1. Use an Iterator

We can change how we iterate by replacing the enhanced for-loop with a while loop that uses an Iterator object. The Iterator allows us to safely remove the matching element because we are not calling remove() directly on the list object

2. Populate a separate list to keep track of the items to be removed

This approach avoids having to introduce an Iterator object, but it requires another list to keep track of the names we want to remove